# Duplicity - save backup to multiple destinations

Tags: shell-script, backup, sftp, duplicity

Is it possible to configure duplicity to save the generated backup to multiple destinations without doing the whole backup process twice?

Something like `duplicty --full --volsize 1024 -v5 sftp://user@host.com/folder /save/also/to/server/folder`

If I do a full backup every two weeks, I want to save that full backup to a folder on my server where I can download it **and** on a sftp backup space (which is not reachable from the outside).

If I downloaded the backup, I would delete it on the server (because I have not that much space on my server).
Is there an easy way of doing this with duplicity directly, or did I need to create a custom shell script which does all this stuff?

Comment: execute duplicity several time with different destination ?

Comment: yes, but this would lead to multiple backup processes (multiple times packaging of backup files, encrypting, etc.) which is inefficient (huge server load).

Comment: how about the multi backend in mirror mode as described in the man page<br/>
&nbsp; http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html#sect18 <br>
? ..ede/duply.net

Comment: Thank you. This seems also a good way to do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [github of duplicity](https://github.com/duplicati/duplicati/issues/234), this feature is still in the to do list.
I think the easier way is to make a small shell script that will move the file at the end the process.

```
#!/bin/bash
duplicty --full --volsize 1024 -v5  /local save/folder && \
rsync /local save/folder user@host.com/folder || \
printf "an error occurs during the transfer\n"
```

**It's a code sample it needs to be tested**

The idea is if duplicity return 0 (no error) on the local backup then it runs rsync to send the file to the remote `host.com` and if one of the commands fails a small error message is written.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but your referring to `Duplicati` rather than `Duplicity` in your github link...
Seems that I need to do this by hand via shell script... Thank you for the suggested script.

Comment: OK you're completely right. I'm sorry I've been fool by google approximation algorithm though as duplicati is mainly base on duplicity I think it's still apply.